# In Visual Studio 2022 the Published nuget package in artifact with version number and suffix are missing

Tags: azure, visual-studio, devops, visual-studio-2022, azure-artifacts

We published latest version with build suffix as environment. It is published in the artifact feed but it is not showing in Visual Studio.

The versions with just build number like 2.0.1 is showing and missing 2.0.1-env.

Included version suffix in `.csproj`

Included version suffix in version number in Azure pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rules of NuGet package versioning, any version number has a **`-Suffix`** will be considered as a **`pre-release`** package version. See "[**NuGet Package version Reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning)".

In Visual Studio, on the "**`Manage NuGet Packages...`**" window, it will not list the **`pre-release`** package versions by default.

To let the **`pre-release`** package versions can be listed, you need to enable the "**`Include prerelease`**" option on the window.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you this helped and able to get all versions

Comment: @ManasaTanmayee, You're welcome. And glad that my answer can help you. Maybe, you can accept it as the solution of this case. This could be helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.